# Call phtml File in Observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, phtml, popup

How can I call a `.phtml` file in Observer?

I want to show popup window when **event observer** fires after customer login so I can call `phtml` file that contains html popup?

So After Customer logged-in a popup appear on the screen directly that contain string text.

**Observer declaration in config.xml:**

```
<frontend>
        <events>
            <customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <mumodule_model_observer>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                        <method>my_custom_event</method>
                    </mymodule_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>
        </events>
    </frontend>
```

**My Observer Class:**

```
<?php

class Company_MyModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function my_custom_event($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    }
}
```

Base on : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38117362/6041121

Comment: hmm, why would you need to get a .phtml template in php to show as a popup? If you give me a bit of more context I might be able to help you out. E.g. what is the event for, when is it triggered etc.

Comment: @AndréFerraz, i've update my question. i want to show popup after the customer logged-in.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might not give you a full explanation but it should help you get started with development.

First you don't really need a observer for this, this should be done on the front-end.

Just add a new `block` which uses your phtml template to the `customer_account_index`. So something like this:

```
<customer_account_index>
        <block type="template/type" as="customname" name="actualname" template="phtml-template">
        </block>
</customer_account_index>
```

Your phtml template would contain the JS logic for the pop up. (I'm assuming you know the basics of magento so I assume you know what those nodes mean.)